# How can you change Mac excel 2011 to separate using commas, not semicolons?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have Excel 2011 on my Mac, and when I try to export a .xls file into .csv I end up having a semicolon separated file instead of .csv.

p.s. The System preferences for my keyboard input is Italian

What is the matter?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Excel for Mac currently has no setting to change the CSV separator from the app itself.

The chosen value separator depends on your *Region*
and your region's default number separators. 
To change them, go to “System Preferences” > “Language & Region”:

[image: System Preferences > Language & Region]

Then you need to verify the number separators in “Advanced …” > “General”.

[image: Advanced > General]

Here are the rules Excel uses to determine how it saves CSV files:

- If your language / region / locale uses comma (`,`) for decimal separation
  (i.e., π (pi) is displayed as `3,1416`),
  then Excel will save using semi-colons (`;`)
- If it uses a dot (`.`, a.k.a. full stop or period),
  then it will delimit with commas (`,`).

Note:

- You need to change your general region for it to work. For example, if your region is Germany (which uses `,` for decimal separation), Excel will always use `;` for CSVs, even when changing the decimal point under “Advanced” settings. You could, for example, if you want `,` as a CSV separator, choose the United States as a region.
- You need to relaunch Excel for it to notice. Quit the app, change the region, then start it again.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. I've tried both of your solutions....

Comment: Works repeatably here, switch both number & currency comma separators to 'dot' separators & vice versa. Relaunch Excel, open xlsx file, save as csv or windows csv, it saves with the alternate comma/semi-colon

Comment: I tried again, it doesn't work....  both http://i59.tinypic.com/2z4lt3m.png AND
http://i57.tinypic.com/13yfbci.jpg

Comment: I haven't tested when the language is set to Italian, but it might be worth testing with yours set to UK English - as it's definitely switching here

Comment: changing the decimal separator didnt work for me. I add to change the whole "region" from "France" to "United States".

Comment: I expect this is going to be one of those settings that depends on your native language, input language & chosen separator.

Comment: I tried to clarify your post – I noticed that the actual decimal point settings don't matter to Excel. It's the region that needs to change. So for me, living in Germany, I had to change it to US to correctly interpret CSV with commas. I consider this a bug or at least a lack of features in Excel, which should have an option to override the system's settings.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a compromise because we are forced yo set the region to something that it's not the "actual" region.

Comment: Best answer, it saves my days. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 6):

I've tried the accepted answer with no success. (High Sierra + Excel 16.10)
My only option has been to use open office, far away from Excel in this feature.

Comment: +1 Installed OpenOffice and got what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Another option is to add "sep=," as the first line of the csv file.

Comment: +1 for sep= :DD

Comment: +1 this should be THE answer. Gold for `sep=,`. I needed tabs: `sep=\t`

Comment: How does one 'add something to the first line of the csv file'? Like, what does it mean and how do I do that if I'm in Excel?

Comment: Open the file with TextEdit or another basic text editor, create a new line at the top of the file by hitting Enter and then type `sep=,`.

It may tell Excel how to read your file but it doesn't stop it from overriding to semicolons when saving from what I've tried...

Answer (score -1):

One more solution.

1. Select the column.
2. Click on **Data**, then click on **Text to columns**.
3. Follow the wizard as follows, Delimited -> Select comma, Tab as delimiters -> Finish.